# How do you use `ProjectRef` to reference a local project in sbt 1.x?

Tags: scala, sbt

There's a lot of vague handwaving in other answers, or things referring to much older versions of sbt (ie. 0.12.x) about this, but no one actually seems to answer the question.

Given I have a folder, and I have run:

```
sbt new scala/scala-seed.g8
name [Scala Seed Project]: one

sbt new scala/scala-seed.g8
name [Scala Seed Project]: two
```

I now have a directory structure that looks like this:

```
8   ./one/build.sbt
8   ./one/...
8   ./two/build.sbt
8   ./two/...
80  .
```

Right, so I now go and change the `example` namespace in `one` and `two`, so the code looks like this in the respective `Hello.scala` files:

```
package example.two

object Hello extends Greeting {
}

trait Greeting {
  lazy val greeting: String = "hello two"
}
```

and:

```
package example.one

object Hello extends Greeting with App {
  println(greeting)
  println(example.two.Hello.greeting)
}

trait Greeting {
  lazy val greeting: String = "hello one"
}
```

Now, how exactly do I make the code in `one` compile and run?

From the reading I've done, it appears I should do something similar to this in `one/project/Dependencies.scala`:

```
import sbt._

object Dependencies {
  lazy val scalaTest = "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5"
  lazy val two = ProjectRef(file("../two"), "two") <------------ ADD THIS
}
```

and this in the `one/build.sbt`:

```
import Dependencies._

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .dependsOn(two) <--------------------- ADD THIS
  .settings(
    inThisBuild(List(
      organization := "com.example",
      scalaVersion := "2.12.7",
      version      := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
    )),
    name := "one",
    libraryDependencies += scalaTest % Test
  )
```

...but it doesn't work:

```
92-168-1-4:one doug$ sbt run
[info] Loading settings for project global-plugins from idea.sbt ...
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/doug/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/doug/tmp/one/project
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/doug/tmp/one/project/target/scala-2.12/sbt-1.0/classes ...
[info] Done compiling.
[info] Loading settings for project root from build.sbt ...
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/doug/tmp/two/project
[info] Loading settings for project root from build.sbt ...
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: No project 'two' in 'file:/Users/doug/tmp/two/'.
[error] Valid project IDs: root
[error]     at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:26)
```

What does '[error] Valid project IDs: root' mean?

Am I doing this completely wrong, and should eg. be using `sbt publishLocal` or something?

I can't find any meaningful documentation on how you're supposed to consume local libraries that are *not* submodules on the current project; did I miss part of the sbt documentation?

The section on `Inter-project dependencies` in [the 1.x documentation](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/sbt-reference.pdf) doesn't seem to explain this at all, it just talks about tracking references...

help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The full error message is:

```
No project 'two' in 'file:/Users/doug/tmp/two/'.
Valid project IDs: root
at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:26)
```

So the problem is that your folder `two` doesn't contain a project called `two`, but only a project called `root` (as created by the g8 template). Note that the `name := …` doesn't matter here, this only sets the name in the project metadata but not the name that sbt itself uses to refer to the project.

To proceed, you can try:

- changing `lazy val root` into `lazy val two` in the `two/build.sbt` file
- changing `ProjectRef(…, "two")` into `ProjectRef(…, "root")`