# Is there "any" possible way to Sync a local Scala library with our current project in order to have some sort of "hot reloading" of it?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I've been creating some projects in Scala, and there might be already several components that I constantly use , reuse or implement in different ways, I want to start putting all that stuff in some sort of a library but the problem is that I really want to have the chance to check its implementation while working, like the nice "Hot reloading" that the revolver plugin brings whenever we require to see the changes of our code in the console

For now its clear that whenever I want to publish something setup my local build.sbt file and publish it

```
sbt publishLocal
```

And then bring them as

```
"eu.myproject" %% "my-lib" % "1.0.0"
```

But I really would appreciate a way to work with this libraries with some real time sync in order to see the changes without having to publish them for each change

---

UPDATE

So thanks to ***Matthias Berndt*** I manage to update a project , with some nice hot reload still with revolver by configuring the sbt file as

```
lazy val root = Project ....
  .dependsOn(
    ProjectRef(file("/HOME/my-lib"), "my-lib"))
```

I still will research a nice pattern to bring some more local and published libraries in order to have them in dev and prod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `ProjectRef` to add the library as a subproject to the build system of the program that uses the library.

Check out this question: [How do you use `ProjectRef` to reference a local project in sbt 1.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53028440/how-do-you-use-projectref-to-reference-a-local-project-in-sbt-1-x)

This blog post should also be helpful:
https://eed3si9n.com/hot-source-dependencies-using-sbt-sriracha

Comment: This was really useful to start my research, thanks Matthias, for now I found great to just configure it in my build.sbt the property dependsOn, I will continue researching and updating this question, my next goal is to give me the chance to easily switch between both, I still didnt get the plugin from sriracha